# Vertically center text next to a custom checbox?

Tags: html, css

I have found a few posts related to this subject, but no answers seem to be working in my scenario, I am assuming due to my custom class for the checkbox.

Essentially I just want the text next to the checkbox to always vertically align with it, but the vertical alignment behavior is different based on whether the checkbox is checked or not.

I have made the `font-size`, `height`, and `line-height` equivalent for the text and checkbox, which seems to not have made a difference. I have also tried `content: "\200b";` in the css but that also seems to not make a difference.

Also, I am unable to use "newer" html/css things because this is for an application that uses an older version of html/css before flexbox.

```css
.lvl1Name {
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.checkboxBig {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #144b68;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.checkboxBig:hover {
  background: #80AED1;
}

.checkboxBig:checked {
  background: #DAE5EB;
}

.checkboxBig:checked:after {
  content: "\2713";
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #144b68;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.checkboxBig:checked:hover {
  background: #80AED1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="checkboxBig" type="checkbox">
  <span class="lvl1Name">Testing</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just apply `vertical-align: middle` to both elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). In the snippet, I added a class of `checkbox-wrapper` to allow for targeting the `div`, and used [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) to center it.

```css
.checkbox-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.lvl1Name {
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.checkboxBig {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #144b68;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.checkboxBig:hover {
  background: #80AED1;
}

.checkboxBig:checked {
  background: #DAE5EB;
}

.checkboxBig:checked:after {
  content: "\2713";
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #144b68;
  line-height: 9px;
}

.checkboxBig:checked:hover {
  background: #80AED1;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
  <input class="checkboxBig" type="checkbox">
  <span class="lvl1Name">Testing</span>
</div>
```

Additionally, you could position the `.lvl1Name` if flex isn't an option. For that class, add a `position:relative` and a negative `top` value:

```
.lvl1Name {
  position:relative;
  top:-7px;
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that I am unable to use "newer" things like flexbox because this is for an application using an older version of HTML and CSS.

Comment: You need to support IE9? Everything else is already supported.

Comment: this is for an "offline" application, the html/css/js will not be getting rendered in a browser. It's a corporate application that doesn't have a plan to update its internal renderer soon.

Comment: Added an additional solution, hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for accommodating me with the non-flexbox solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the `div` containing both the elements and use `flex box` css.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.lvl1Name {
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.checkboxBig {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #144b68;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.checkboxBig:hover {
  background: #80AED1;
}

.checkboxBig:checked {
  background: #DAE5EB;
}

.checkboxBig:checked:after {
  content: "\2713";
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #144b68;
  line-height: 9px;
}

.checkboxBig:checked:hover {
  background: #80AED1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input class="checkboxBig" type="checkbox">
  <span class="lvl1Name">Testing</span>
</div>
```

If `flex box` is not something that you are looking for, then you can use `vertical-align`.

```css
.lvl1Name {
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkboxBig {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #144b68;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkboxBig:hover {
  background: #80AED1;
}

.checkboxBig:checked {
  background: #DAE5EB;
}

.checkboxBig:checked:after {
  content: "\2713";
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #144b68;
  line-height: 9px;
}

.checkboxBig:checked:hover {
  background: #80AED1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="checkboxBig" type="checkbox">
  <span class="lvl1Name">Testing</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that I am unable to use "newer" things like flexbox because this is for an application using an older version of HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `position: absolute` and `top` property on `.lvlName` class and set `position: realtive` property on the parent element.
**position** property sets how an element is positioned in a document.

For more about `position` property see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
.lvl1Name {
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}
.main-div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
.lvl1Name {
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

.checkboxBig {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #144b68;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.checkboxBig:hover {
  background: #80AED1;
}

.checkboxBig:checked {
  background: #DAE5EB;
}

.checkboxBig:checked:after {
  content: "\2713";
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #144b68;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.checkboxBig:checked:hover {
  background: #80AED1;
}

.main-div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <input class="checkboxBig" type="checkbox">
  <span class="lvl1Name">Testing</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your case**, with the same `font-size`, `line-height` and `height` just add `vertical-align: bottom;` to the `checkbox`.

```css
.lvl1Name {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.checkboxBig {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #144b68;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.checkboxBig:hover {
  background: #80AED1;
}

.checkboxBig:checked {
  background: #DAE5EB;
}

.checkboxBig:checked:after {
  content: "\2713";
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #144b68;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.checkboxBig:checked:hover {
  background: #80AED1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="checkboxBig" type="checkbox">
  <span class="lvl1Name">Testing</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `display:flex` in the div. Using flexbox usually helps to solve a lot of problems like this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that I am unable to use "newer" things like flexbox because this is for an application using an older version of HTML and CSS. I have now updated my post.